# Category of functors not cartesian closed

Tags: category-theory

My question is

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a small and cartesian closed category, and
>   $\mathcal{D}$ is some small category, must $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{D}}$
>   be cartesian closed?

A counterexample would be nice. If $\mathcal{C}$ is instead Set then this is true, but in general the answer I believe is no, right?

Comment: The main problem is the existence of limits and colimits. Otherwise the functor category is cartesian closed: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/305144/5191).