# Is the arrow category of cartesian closed category cartesian closed?

Tags: category-theory

in a cartesian closed category $\mathcal{C}$. if we have $f: A\to X$ and $g: B\to Y$

- then because the functor $(\_)^A$ is continuous, we have $g':B^A\to Y^A$
- composing $\text{id}\times f: Y^X\times A\to Y^X\times X$ and the evaluation map $\epsilon: Y^X\times X\to Y$ we have a function $Y^X\times A\to Y$ then we have induced a function $f': Y^X\to Y^A$
- we have the pushout of the two function $f'$ and $g'$ denoted $(Y, B)^{(X, A)}$

it seems that in the arrow category $\text{Id}\downarrow \text{Id}$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the object of type $(Y, B)^{(X, A)}\to Y^A$ in the pushout diagram is the exponential object of the two object $f$ and $g$. but I cannot formalize it, is this true?

What if restirct $f$ and $g$ to be monomorphism and replace the arrow category with the category of monomorphism pairs? notice that in this situation the morphisms in arrow category is only determined by the lower one of the arrow pair

Comment: @Zhen We've received a flag that this question is not a duplicate since the second part of the question is still unanswered. Can you check to see if this is the case, and if that's true, remove your duplicate vote? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow category of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is (isomorphic to) the category $\mathcal{C}^{\mathbf{2}}$, where $\mathbf{2}$ is the category $\bullet \rightarrow \bullet$ with two objects and one nontrivial morphism. The fact that this category is cartesian closed follows from a more general fact: if $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed and $\mathcal{D}$ is any small category, then the category $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{D}}$ of functors $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ and natural transformations between them is cartesian closed. Finite products are given pointwise, and the exponential $F^G$ of functors $F,G : \mathcal{D} \rightrightarrows \mathcal{C}$ is defined by the exponential adjunction in $\mathcal{C}$: the correspondence is given by
$$\begin{matrix} (F^G)(A) \to TA \\ \hline FA \to GA \times TA \end{matrix}$$
naturally in $A \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{D}$ and $T : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$.

A good exercise (for you) would  be to check what this means in the case $\mathcal{D} = \mathbf{2}$.

Comment: What? Your adjunction is backwards. You need limits (and cartesian closedness) in $\mathcal{C}$ to define exponential objects in $[\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{C}]$.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the question is essentially answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305144/5191). Your guess is half right: the codomain part of the exponential object $(Y, B)^{(X, A)}$ in $[\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}]$ is indeed just $Y^X$, i.e. the exponential object of the codomain parts. However the domain is more complicated; it is defined by the following pullback diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>>> Y^X \\
@VVV @VV{Y^f}V\\
B^A @>>{g^A}> Y^A 
\end{CD}
Incidentally, the top horizontal arrow is the morphism part of the exponential object.

Notice that if $g : B \to Y$ is a monomorphism then $g^A : B^A \to Y^A$ is a monomorphism, so we deduce that the full subcategory of $[\mathbb{2}, \mathcal{C}]$ spanned by the monomorphisms is closed under exponential objects. Since it is also closed under (finite) products, it follows that it is a cartesian closed category.

Comment: I am confused by this answer: the cartesian structure on $[2,C]$ is pointwise (limits in functor categories), so if this was true, by uniqueness of adjoints, the [pushout-product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pushout-product) would coincide with pointwise product (by "pointwise" I mean that the pair $(u : A_0 \to A_1),(v : B_0 \to B_1)$ just goes to $u \times v : A_0 \times B_0 \to A_1 \times B_1$). Is this true? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: What does the pushout–product have to do with the question? (Yes, OP mentions pushout but I presume that's a typo for pullback since we have a cospan rather than a span.)

Comment: Let's say I want to prove that $Set^2$ is a CCC. There is an adjunction $A \times \_ \dashv [A,-]$, where the exponential is the usual exponential in a presheaf category. Apparently, in this case $[f,g]$ is the pullback-hom of f,g. But the pullback hom is also right adjoint to the pushout product, right? So, uniqueness of adjoints: cartesian structure = pushout product in $Set^2$, and this feels very wrong.

Comment: So, either 1) pullback-hom is not right adjoint to pushout-product. Yet, I think I proved and used this fact for some time already. 2) there is no mistake, and indeed $\times$ coincides with pushout-product. I didn't cook up a counterexample (because I didn't want to: I don't need one to believe it's false). Where is the mistake then?

Comment: This is a different but related thing. You are talking about an object in the arrow category whose codomain is a pullback of a span of exponential objects; I am talking about an object in the arrow category whose domain is a pullback of a span of exponential objects.